# gsl_rng functions: in what order do they compile

Tags: c, random, gsl

I am learning gsl_rng library and found an interesting question.

I understand that the environment variables (`GSL_RNG_TYPE` and `GSL_RNG_SEED`) can be used to set library variables (`gsl_rng_default` and `gsl_rng_default_seed`) during run time (without re-compile). You just need to add `gsl_rng_env_setup()` and then change these two variables in terminal before do `./a.out`.

However, if I specifically set the `gsl_rng_default` and `gsl_rng_default`_seed in the code (eg. use "taus" and "12"), with the same program compiled, now I cannot change the seed value at run time but can still change the generator type.

I am new to this stuff so probably I missed something. But can anyone help me understand why this happen? Why do these two variables behave differently? Is there an order or over-write problem?

Here is my code (simple practice):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

int main (void)
{
  const gsl_rng_type * T;   /*generator type*/
  gsl_rng * r;          /*rng instance*/

  int i, n = 20;

  gsl_rng_env_setup();      /*read from environment variable*/


  T = gsl_rng_default;  /*choose default generator type*/

  gsl_rng_default = gsl_rng_mt19937;
  gsl_rng_default_seed = 12;

  r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);    /*create an instance*/

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
      double u = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
      printf ("%.5f\n", u);
    }



  gsl_rng_free (r);     /*free all memory associated with r*/

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we step through the code in execution order, we see what happens:

```
gsl_rng_env_setup();      /*read from environment variable*/
```

so `gsl_rnd_default` and `gsl_rng_default_seed` now contain the values from the environment, or if they weren't set, the library defaults.

```
T = gsl_rng_default;  /*choose default generator type*/
```

`T` now contains a copy of the environment value

```
gsl_rng_default = gsl_rng_mt19937;
gsl_rng_default_seed = 12;
```

now we've overwritten both the values from earlier

```
r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);    /*create an instance*/
```

At this point, since `gsl_rng_alloc()` uses the generator type we pass in the parameter, it doesn't matter that `gsl_rng_default` was overwritten because we're passing `T`, and that still contains its copy of the value from beforehand. However, since `gsl_rng_alloc()` will go ahead and use the *current* value of `gsl_rnd_default`, it gets the 12 that we put there.

If you were to assign your default values *before* calling `gsl_rng_env_setup()`, you'd overwrite the library defaults, then those values you set will be overwritten if the environment variables are set, or passed through if they aren't, which seems like the behaviour you really want.

Comment: I would also say confusion is excusable since this a pretty poor interface design - having one default that is written to and used implicitly, and one "default" that has to read and explicitly passed as a parameter is... questionable at best.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But as you said, due to the execution order, I explicitly overwrite the library values to mt19937 and 12 even after the program reads values from user, which occur earlier during gsl_rng_env_setup(). However, the program still use whatever generator type user input but stick with the seed value 12. So, if I input taus and 4 during run-time, the program uses taus and 12 as the result. It's really weird. I expect both variables behave the same way